# How to store a data-key value of a gridview row on an element's .data expando with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, gridview

In a grid view, I want to store one of the data-key values of the current row, in a  element as an expando property by using the .data feature of jQuery.

I would be the happiest if I an do it on data-binding.

See the grid view marjup with the comment TODO to have a better pciture please.

The main goal is to be able to obtain the Id -which is a data-key of each row- on the  element in the end.

Can you advice?

Thanks!

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewPayments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id">
        <Columns>
        <
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due" HeaderText="Due"/>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a class="quick-update" href="#">
                   <%#Eval("Status.Name").ToString()%></a>
      <!-- TODO:
          Store Eval("Id").ToString() as a data in this <a> element -->
      <!-- so that I can  reach it later as follows:
         $('.quick-update').data('Id') -->

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery supports the data-attribute for storage which means you can simply do the following.**

```
<a class="quick-update" href="#" data-id='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>Click here </a>
```

**Then simply use**

```
$(".quick-update").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: I can't find it in the jQuery doc, any documentation to confirm support of data-id attribute?

Comment: Wow! I did not know this site btw! Thanks Marko!